# How to stack matrices in a single column table

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to store 20 automatically generated Matrices in a single column Matrix, so this last Matrix would be a 1x20 Matrix.
For this I am using numpy and vstack, but it doesn't work, it Keep on getting the following error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Even though all the Matrices tham I'm trying to stack together have the same dimensions (881 x 882)

So I'd like to know what is wrong About this or if there is any other way to stack all the Matrices in a way that if one of them is needed I can access easily to that one.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Your numbers and description don't make sense.  A single column array would have shape (n,1).  If the arrays are all (881,882), I can see stacking them to make a `(20,881,882)` array, or vstack to make a `(20*881, 882)`.

Comment: How are you trying to use `vstack`?  If you are using `vstack` in a loop the problem could be with the initial `empty` array.  It's best to collect all arrays in a list, and do one `stack` or `vstack` at the end.  Iterative `vstack` is slow, and hard to get right.

Comment: have to agree with hpaulj.  If you really have ndarrays with the same dimmensions then your error should not happen.  It seems like you may have a false assumption about that.  As an aside, to stack them correctly into what you want, you will have to use expand_dims to add a row so that the arrays are 1 x 881 x 882 and then when you stack them it will result in a 20 x 881 x 882 single array

Answer (score 0):

Try to change dimensions with expand and squeeze functions:

```
y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0) # dim 20 become 1x20
y = np.squeeze(x, axis=0)     # dim 1x20 become 20
```

Comment: Thanks but reshaping is not what I need

Comment: For changing dimension see expand and squeeze from numpy

Comment: I do not want to Change dimensions, I want to storage 20 different Matrices inside a column with 20 rows, so in every cell there is a matrix